# Помогите оптимизировать рабочий код. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно найти максимальное произведение двух чисел в списке. Числа могут быть и отрицательные. Код рабочий, но тестирующая программа выдаёт Time Limit Exceeded. Как можно его оптимизировать? Интересно можно ли преобразовать имеющихся 2 for в list comprehension, ибо у меня за 3 часа это сделать так и не получилось.

```
def composition():
    s = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    lists = []
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] * s[j] > total and i != j:
                total = s[i] * s[j]
                lists.append(s[i])
                lists.append(s[j])
    a = lists[-1]
    b = lists[-2]
    if a < b:
        return a, b
    return b, a
print(*composition())
```

Comment: максимальное произведение двух чисел?

Comment: Текст задачи следующий:
Дан список, заполненный произвольными целыми числами. Найдите в этом списке два числа, произведение которых максимально. Выведите эти числа в порядке неубывания.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

самый короткий код без использования каких либо библиотек :)

```
data = sorted([*map(int, input().split())])

print(data[0], data[1]) if data[0] * data[1] > data[-1] * data[-2] else print(data[-1], data[-2])
```

более короткое решение:

```
data = sorted([*map(int, input().split())])

print(*max(data[:2], data[-2:], key=lambda obj: obj[0] * obj[1]))
```

Comment: Сдача задачи
100/100
OK

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы, подкоректировал для вывода в порядке возрастания и всё ок!

Comment: элегантное решение)

Comment: @MaxU, добавил второй вариант - еще более короткий.. и надеюсь более элегантный :)

Answer (score 3):

ну если решать совсем в лоб, вот просто в лобешник, то

```
data = [*map(int, input().split())]

# оцениваем только положительные числа
max1pos = max(data[0], data[1])
max2pos = min(data[0], data[1])

for value in data:
    if value <= 0:
        continue

    if value >= max1pos:
        max1pos, max2pos = value, max1pos
    elif value > max2pos:
        max2pos = value

# оцениваем только отрицательные числа числа
max1neg = min(data[0], data[1])
max2neg = max(data[0], data[1])

for value in data:
    if value > 0:
        continue

    if value <= max1neg:
        max1neg, max2neg = value, max1neg
    elif value < max2neg:
        max2neg = value

# выводим результат
print(max1pos, max2pos) if max1pos * max2pos > max1neg * max2neg else print(max1neg, max2neg)
```

вот так даже получше (покороче):

```
data = [*map(int, input().split())]

max1pos, max2pos = max(data[0], data[1]), min(data[0], data[1])
max1neg, max2neg = max2pos, max1pos

for value in data:
    if value <= 0:
        if value <= max1neg:
            max1neg, max2neg = value, max1neg
        elif value < max2neg:
            max2neg = value
    else:
        if value >= max1pos:
            max1pos, max2pos = value, max1pos
        elif value > max2pos:
            max2pos = value

# выводим результат
print(max1pos, max2pos) if max1pos * max2pos > max1neg * max2neg else print(max1neg, max2neg)
```

Answer (score 3):

Предположу, что числа в последовательности являются уникальнымы. Для поиска всех возможных комбинаций неповторяющихся отлично подходит [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). Для повторяющихся — [combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement).

```
from itertools import combinations

data = map(int, input().split()))
uq_pairs = combinations(data)   # только уникальные неповторяющиеся пары

result = max(
    uq_pairs, 
    key=lambda x: x[0] * x[1],  # функция-ключ для поиска максимума
)
```

Comment: Наивная реализация (не Cython) — присутствует по ссылкам в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо, кое что новое узнал для себя :)

Comment: В встроенных модулях functools, itertools и operator — скрывается магия :)